# SSH agent forwading with a different key

Tags: github, ssh, remote-access, remote-debugging, remote-server

I have 2 keys, key 1 and key 2.

Key 1 is for ssh on EC2 and key 2 is for GitHub. Now I want to clone a private repository from GitHub on EC2 with key 2 without actually transferring the key 2.

As per my understanding, with ssh agent forwarding I can use key 1 on EC2(for cloning) and then I can use the same key on Github but I don't want to add key 1 in my GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I would:

- generate a key (key3) dedicated for Github, registered to my GitHub account, and stored only on EC2
- use [SSH Agent Forwarding](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/25/what-is-ssh-agent-forwarding-and-how-do-you-use-it/) with key3.

That way, I have a dedicated key (which I can rescind at any time) for GitHub from EC2, without interfering with key1 or key2.